# ios core-plot Touch not detected on right side of chart

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a scatter plot chart that allows for a user to touch various areas on the chart.  On the right half of the chart touch events do not register.

I've implemented the following method.

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    NSLog(@"Touched.");
    return YES;
}
```

Is there a property that I'm missing that sets the touch area of a given chart?  Or any ideas what may be occurring?

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? Does the graph display correctly?

Comment: That's a good question.  I thought that I was 1.4 but it could be 1.3 as I may have imported it from an older project.  I don't see an easy way to detect the version. Do you know how I can check this? Yes the graphs are working great with all the functionality.

Comment: I just updated graded to 1.4 and still experiencing the same issue.  If I resize the graph to 50% of the size then the whole chart will register clicks.  When I go back to 100% anything to the right of the middle tick doesn't register a touch....

Comment: Just to add some more context to this issue.  This graph is a scatter plot that resides on the first view controller of a tab based app. If I move this View controller, with this scatter plot, to the second or third tab the graph loads and all touch points are registered. So it seems the graph functionality isn't fully loaded when on the first view controller.

Comment: I've heard similar reports from other people. It has something to do with the tab bar, but I haven't been able to reproduce it in testing and I don't know what the solution is.

Comment: @Eric - thanks for your help. I'll let you know if I uncover anything that could help identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@hellojello - It might be because of below scenarios:
1. some other view overlapping onto the plot. 
2. Different Layers of graph might be overlapped avoiding detection(Not sure in your scenario)

Debugging option for 
**1**: If you are testing on simulator, Enable **color Blended Layers** (simulator menu-> "Debug" -> "color BlendedLayers") 

 **2**: Increase detection point to large value say @"400". Remove userinteraction to all other layers.